# Java - infinite recursive for loop

Tags: java, recursion, for-loop, infinite-loop

I am trying to calculate the number of combinations of sequences (ArrayList) that can be stacked, but each row cannot contain any of the elements that are contained in adjacent rows up to a specified "HEIGHT". I have a list of lists, "rowCombos" (global) which are all the possible combinations of elements that can be in each row. My code should cycle through the "rowCombos" to see which row Combo can be placed on top of the proceeding row, following the contraints mentioned above. Once the "panel" reaches the HEIGHT input parameter, it should increment the counter, and then drop out of the recursive method. The issue I'm running into is a stackOverflow and I have ran a debug to see where it is hanging up. It seems that each thread works it's way through the method, and then hangs up on the consecutive recursive call... Can any of you guys spot where my issue is?

```
public static void
buildPanels(ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> panel, int HEIGHT)
{
    if (panel.size() == HEIGHT)
    {
        mainCount++;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for ( List<Float> row:rowCombos)
        {
            boolean duplicateFound = false;
            if (!panel.isEmpty())
            {
                for (Float element:row)
                {
                    if (panel.get(panel.size() - 1).contains(element))
                    {
                        duplicateFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (panel.isEmpty() || !(duplicateFound))
            {
                panel.add((ArrayList<Float>) row);
                buildPanels(panel, HEIGHT);
            }
        } // end of for
    } // end of else
} // end of buildPanels
```

Comment: Well, it's difficult to trace without knowing what data the `List` contains.

Comment: Where are your `System.out.println(...)` statements? The ones you could use to help debug your problem?

Comment: A possible (simple) list would be
{[3.0, 6.0, 9.0],
[3.0, 7.5],
[4.5, 7.5],
[4.5, 9.0]}

I have the system.out's on my end, figured I'd take 'em out of the code I posted above since it would just clutter things up. I can post that if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This code is begging to run into a stackoverflow.  Read the logic:

Lets say the panel is empty....

1. Call `buildPanel`
2. Set `duplicateFound` to `false`
3. If no `!(duplicateFound)`, call `buildPanel`

   ```
   boolean duplicateFound = false;
   if (!panel.isEmpty())
   {
       for (Float element:row)
       {
           if (panel.get(panel.size() - 1).contains(element))
           {
               duplicateFound = true;
           }
       }
   }
   if (panel.isEmpty() || !(duplicateFound))
   {
       panel.add((ArrayList<Float>) row);
       buildPanels(panel, HEIGHT);
   }
   ```